# SolrCloud Indexing Issue after 6,00,000 of records

Tags: solrcloud

after indexing 6,00,000+ records with external zookeeper and default configuration, I get the following error.

> `{"responseHeader":{"status":500,"QTime":25407},"error":{"msg":"Server Error\n\n\n\nrequest: http://192.168.12.104:7574/solr/jiffy_shard1_replica1/update?update.chain=add-unknown-fields-to-the-schema&update.distrib=TOLEADER&distrib.from=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.12.104%3A8983%2Fsolr%2Fjiffy_shard2_replica2%2F&wt=javabin&version=2","trace":"org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Server Error\n\n\n\nrequest: http://192.168.12.104:7574/solr/jiffy_shard1_replica1/update?update.chain=add-unknown-fields-to-the-schema&update.distrib=TOLEADER&distrib.from=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.12.104%3A8983%2Fsolr%2Fjiffy_shard2_replica2%2F&wt=javabin&version=2\n\tat org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient$Runner.run(ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient.java:251)\n\tat org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor$1.run(ExecutorUtil.java:210)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)\n","code":500}}`

Comment: Could you please post or edit your question with the definition of the update.chain?

Comment: I have used their default configuration sir..

Comment: The update chain is add-unknown-fields-to-the-schema